# Batch - function - parameters not working

Tags: batch-file, windows-7-x64

on Windows 7 (64) I try to make the simplest function call, of course batch oddity is ruining it once again

I dont understand why it is not taking the parameter, all examples point to this way of doing it

```
@ECHO OFF

:import

echo "%~1 %~2"
mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `%~1`;CREATE DATABASE `%~1`"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
mysql -u root %~1 < %~1.sql
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error


call :import "something"

:error

@echo errors !!

pause
```

it displays this :

```
" "
ERROR 1102 (42000) at line 1: Incorrect database name ''
errors !!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

seems like %~1 never contains anything

Comment: How do you start your batch file?

Comment: Remove the `@echo off` so you can see which command line and what values are used.

Comment: Did you mean `%1` rather than `%~1` etc?

Comment: And split the mysql commands onto 2 separate lines...

Comment: I think you meant to use single quotes instead of back quotes in mysql command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :import "something"
if errorlevel 1 call :error
exit /b

:import
echo "%~1 %~2"
mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `%~1`;CREATE DATABASE `%~1`"
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 1
mysql -u root "%~1" < "%~1.sql"
if errorlevel 1 exit /b 2
exit /b

:error
@echo errors !!
pause
exit /b
```

In posted question code, `:import` is a label.
The interpreter will ignore the line, unless
`goto` or `call` is used to execute from the label.
What the question code is doing is going from top
to bottom until it reaches the `call` line which
calls `:import` above then proceeds down with the
called label. The code is not getting that far as
the arguments of `%~1` and `%~2` are undefined, as
they are being interpreted as script arguments
instead of called label arguments, so `mysql`
errors which causes `goto error` to occur.

The code above instead puts the 2 labels below an
`exit /b` so either of the labels need to be called
to access.
It will now go down from the top, to the
`call :import "something"` line,
which will execute the code in the `:import` label.
Once it reaches an `exit /b`, the called label will
return back to the line of the `call`.
The following line of `if errorlevel 1 call :error`
will `call :error` if `errorlevel` is `set` to 1 or above.

Comment: This is a more complete and detailed answer than mine. While I could tell the function didn't work when placed at the beginning of the file, the explanation above explains why it has to be like that. The details around the exit codes are also well done: +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to structure the batch file a little differently.

The functions should be at the bottom of the file. The "import" label is only run inside of a "call", so don't try to jump out of that label during the call. Take care to use appropriate labels for each GOTO jump.

```
@ECHO OFF

call :import "something1" "something2"
goto end

:import
echo "%~1 %~2"
mysql -u root -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `%~1`;CREATE DATABASE `%~1`"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
mysql -u root %~1 < %~1.sql
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO error
goto endOfImport
:error
@echo errors !!
:endOfImport
goto :eof

:end
pause
```